# In Emacs, where is ispell's personal dictionary stored?

Tags: ispell

In Emacs, where is ispell's personal dictionary stored?, the documentation http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Spelling.html says

> Your personal dictionary is specified by the variable ispell-personal-dictionary. If that is nil, the spelling program looks for a personal dictionary in a default location.

But where is this default location?  In general, how to find out this?

Comment: Here is an example command-line to dump the aspell configuration from the terminal into output to the terminal screen:  `aspell --lang=en dump config`  You can setup an `aspell.conf` in the `etc` directory and then store your personal dictionaries wherever you want.

Comment: **Ask Emacs**: `C-h v ispell-personal-dictionary` (as @Lompik said). If that doesn't tell you all you need to know, click the link that takes you to the source code, and see what it uses as the default value.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`C-h v ispell-personal-dictionary`

```
"File name of your personal spelling dictionary, or nil.
If nil, the default personal dictionary, (\"~/.ispell_DICTNAME\" for ispell or
\"~/.aspell.LANG.pws\" for aspell) is used, where DICTNAME is the name of your
default dictionary and LANG the two letter language code."
```

Comment: Any idea what does "pws" stands for?

Comment: I'm not sure what it stands for but it's just the extension of the file.
http://aspell.net/man-html/Format-of-the-Personal-and-Replacement-Dictionaries.html

Comment: *"Personal Word Set"*? (i have no clue)

Comment: What if there are multiple languages? In hunspell each language has its own `~/.hunspell_es_AR` personal dictionary for each language. Is there still only one personal dictionary for this variable?