# Where is personal dictionary for ispell?

Tags: ispell

[In this page](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch16_05.htm) I read that “the personal word list is normally a file called `.ispell_english` or `.ispell_words` in your home directory."

But I don’t have that file. Is this Unix specific? I’m on a Mac.

I’m trying to find the file where the words I saved are stored.

Note: [This question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/58844/where-is-personal-dictionary-for-ispell-located) is suggested but I don't have `~/.hunspell_default` either.

emacs v.28.1

Comment: It probably depends on which spelling program you actually use: `M-x ispell` actually looks for `aspell`, `ispell` , `hunspell`, `enchant-2` in that order (IIRC). You need to find out which one *you* are using and then find out where the one you are using is keeping your personal list.

Comment: Note that you have to install the spell checking tool separately from Emacs. I use macOS and Emacs rules apply to macOS as much Linux and Windows.  First install the spell checker tool you want to use (I use aspell, but the others also work on macOS) then you might want to customize Emacs to specify which one you use. And to answer your question the file is OK on macOS as much as any Unix-type OS.

Comment: @PRouleau emacs is using `aspell`. From message buffer I find this: "Spell-checking abc.org using aspell with default dictionary...done" Also, "Personal dictionary modified.  Save? (y or n) y Personal dictionary saved." Where can I find this personal dictionary?

Comment: Ok, I found it, it is at `~/.aspell.en.pws` This question also related https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17237/in-emacs-where-is-ispells-personal-dictionary-stored

Answer (score 1):

Emacs ispell.el file provides the `ispell-personal-dictionary` user-option. Its docstring states:

> File name of your personal spelling dictionary, or nil. If nil, the
> default personal dictionary for your spelling checker is used.

The default will depend on the actual spell checking tool.  In Emacs you can select it with the `ispell-program-name` user-option.